# how to load and fill a word template from oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, ms-word, word-template

Would you mind help me how I can load and fill a word template dynamically via oracle form or plsql codes?

I am using oracle 10g.

Comment: Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/, specifically http://ora-00001.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/working-with-office-2007-ooxml-files.html

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way to have a possibility of generating MS Word documents from Oracle (and pl/sql) is to use an additional tool. Here is a comparison of some of them for Oracle and APEX https://explorantum.com/ords/r/w/explorantum/oracle-report-tool-comparison

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be great if you could write an answer to the question instead of simply putting a link here, since the link might go dead in the future, and it's not immediately clear how that comparison helps answer the question.